# Does the Decanter of Endless Water consume an action each turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The Decanter of Endless Water text states that:

> You can use an action to remove the stopper and
>   speak one of three command words, whereupon an
>   amount of fresh water or salt water (your choice) pours
>   out of the flask. The water stops pouring out at the start
>   of your next turn.

Does this mean that an action must be used to each turn to re-engage the item, or can the command words simply be spoken to activate it again?

Answer (score 6):

The answer is right there in your question.

> You can use an action to remove the stopper **and** speak one of three command words

The action used to unstop the item and say its command word are one and the same. And because it specifically states that the water pours out after the word is spoken, you must once again spend the activation action in order to reengage the effect.

Comment: I feel like this is accurate RAW, but logically would vary from game to game. It would really come down to what the command word *is*. If it's "pour," why spend an action on it? You're allowed to speak briefly as a free action, after all.

Comment: That's a fair point. I agree that it could vary game to game, but the question was about the meaning of the text, I.E RAW. For role-play purposes, I would honestly prefer it not stop until you stoppered the bottle again- but that's where DM discretion gets involved.

Comment: The text isn't completely clear either, the and could  separate two different actions, where the time necessary for the latter isn't specified.